# Sending and receiving over socket from list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am having trouble sending and receiving data.  I have a global list containing strings in this format e.g '127.0.0.1 4001\r\n'

How do I send and receive them over the socket when my admin client connects?

Server(Not complete code, just the thread that deals with admin connections)

```
def HandleAdmin(adminSocket,):
    global addressList

    (c,a) = adminSocket.accept()

    for i in addressList:
        print(i)

    ts = ssl.wrap_socket(c, certfile="5cc515_server.crt",
                             keyfile="5cc515_server.key",
                             server_side=True,
                             cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_REQUIRED,
                             ca_certs="5cc515-root-ca.cer")

    if ts.recv(80).decode() == 'Hello\r\n':
        ts.send('Admin-Greetings\r\n'.encode()) 

    if ts.recv(80).decode() == 'Who\r\n':

            ts.send(addr.encode())
    ts.close()
    return
```

Admin Client

```
import ssl
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)

ts = ssl.wrap_socket(s, certfile="100298750.crt",
                        keyfile="100298750.key",
                        ca_certs="5cc515-root-ca.cer")

ts.connect(('127.0.0.1', 4001))

ts.send("Hello\r\n".encode())

addressList = []

if ts.recv(80).decode() == "Admin-Greetings\r\n":

    print("The players currently playing are:\n\n")
    ts.send("Who\r\n".encode())
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting? at which line of the code you have shown?

Comment: I have addr is not defined but that is obvious. The code is unfinished because I do not know how to do it

Comment: Have you tried goggling for: _python socket server_ - there are many examples of coding sockets, get that working then extend it for your usage.

Comment: I have tried but I am unable to find anything relevent to sending each item from a list. Thanks

Comment: Convert the list to a string (maybe using the json module?) send the string. At the receiving end, receive, decode the string. Search for _python json encode decode_ you will find examples.

Comment: I thought the list already contained strings?

Comment: A 'list' is a programming concept - you can't send concepts over TCP. TCP can move bytes around. By encoding your list (whatever it contains, well not whatever, let's assume it's something that can be converted into json, e.g. numbers, strings, and lists/dictionaries containing only numbers and strings) to a single encoded string you will be able to send it over TCP. At the receiving end you will have to know that you are receiving something encoded in json, and decode it. Now go look at the json module and try encoding your list using it. See  https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html

Comment: I don't really get the question. What's the problem with sending each line separately? --- How about you add some 'pseudo code' in your question? I mena, add some explanation of what you want to send and what isn't beeing sent.

Comment: I don't know how to send each string from the list seperately.  That is my question.  I have to send each string seperately in this format 'ip_address port_number\r\n'

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you just send your strings, so you could just join your whole list into one string and send it.

```
msj = "".join(addressList)
ts.send(msj)
```

Of course, if you don't know the length of the message, then you would need to add it to the beggining of your string `msj = unichr(len(msj)) + msj` or `msj = struct.pack('H', len(msj)) + msj` by example.

Also, you could use `pickle` to compact your data into a string and then send its size + pickle, and then decode it at the other end.